# moving files with rsync and delete them after transfer individually

Tags: rsync, scp

I'm using something like

```
rsync -av --remove-source-files user@host:/remotedir/* localdir
```

to move about 100 quite large files from a server to a local machine, which takes about one day. With the command above rsync deletes the source files after the last file has been transfered.

I'm looking for a way to delete each of the about 100 remote files immediately after it has been transfered. I'm not forced to use rsync. All that works through a ssh connection would be fine.

Comment: A combination of find and rsync will do the trick.it will launch your rsync command for each file found.

Comment: This will not work because the rsync command must run on the local machine.

Comment: You can execute find on the remove machine and pipe the result to the local machine's rsync.